# Blank Serial Print AdaFruit BTLE

Tags: arduino-uno

I working on a prototype with an Arduino UNO and an [AdaFruit Low Energy Blue tooth](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1697)

I have an array of uint32_t that I am trying to send via blue tooth to a given device.  I don't think i can send the array so I was trying to send it as a comma separated string.

I can print out each individual index of that array just fine, but its completely blank when i try to make a comma separated String..  See code and comments below.

**Ay Array:**

```
uint32_t items[]= {0,3513728,7925384,0,0,0};
```

**In My Loop:**

```
String output = "";

for(int i = 0; i<6;  i++){

  BTLEserial.print(items[i]); // Prints as expected
  output += getStringForUI32_T(items[i]);
  output+=",";

 }
 BTLEserial.print(output); // prints BLANK
```

I imagine this has something to do with memory but I am at a complete loss.. Please help!

Comment: Does it work when printing to the normal serial monitor? `BTLEserial.print` might not accept a `String` as an input and instead just print out the pointer address. You might have to copy it to a char buffer first (`toCharArray(but,len)`).

Comment: I doesn't work on Serial.println either..  behaves pretty much the same way.  would you mind showing me how to do the buffer way above.. C is not my strongest suite

Comment: There's no reason to concatenate everything into a temporary String - just send each piece in its own call to the sending function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do it directly like:

```
for(int i = 0; i<6;  i++) {
  BTLEserial.print(items[i]);
  BTLEserial.print(',');
}
BTLEserial.println();
```

But with the string I think it would be something like:

```
String output = "";

for(int i = 0; i<6;  i++) {
  output += getStringForUI32_T(items[i]);
  output+=",";
}
BTLEserial.println(output[0]);
```

But as someone else got it working using String on your adafruit thread maybe this is just barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @ChrisStratton How about that for the String object? I didn't realise you could reference the char array of the String using `[]`.